# Reading and Updating data of Oracle DB without License

Tags: oracle, dump

I've got to update the data of an Oracle DB but I'm not the owner and ain't got any Oracle License.
The goal is to explain to my interlocutor how to create a dump from his Oracle DB, to find out how to restore this dump in a DB (a free version of Oracle or something else), update some data in some tables, and then make another dump to send it back to my interlocutor.

So the differents questions I have are:

1- Is it possible to create a dump (maybe in SQL format) without any specifics dependencies to Oracle ?

2- Is there a way to restore this dump in a free lightweight Oracle, or another kind of DB like Postgresql ?

3- Does Oracle, is able to handle any kind of dump et restore it in an Oracle DB or is there any constraints to respect ?

I am very new to Oracle and ain't got, on my personal computer, any possibility to try out the dump/restore by myself; that's why, any help will be appreciated !

Comment: Please keep questions focused, limit it to (oddly enough) a single question per  single question

Comment: You may use any "free" format of data exchange (for example, XML or JSON) which may be parsed by string manipulations and doesn't depend on a specific tool. But you have to write something to do this.

Comment: Thx @astentx for your answer.
The fact is that I would like to keep the solution as simple as possible and using an ETL (or creating one in Python or something) isn't the fastest solution in my point of view.
I'de like to know if there were a solution like pg_dump -> pg_restore but from Oracle to PG and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- Is it possible to create a dump (maybe in SQL format) without any specifics dependencies to Oracle ?

Oracle offers **Data Pump** utilities (export and import) for such purposes. You'd export table (or schema) - result is a ".dmp" file, readable by import utility. You'd then move that file to your own server (see #2 for the rest)

---

> 2- Is there a way to restore this dump in a free lightweight Oracle, or another kind of DB like Postgresql ?

On your own server (which could be a laptop; no problem), you'd install a free Oracle Express Edition (XE) database. Currently, the last version is 21c, but some others should still be available in Oracle Technology Network's *Download* section.

---

> 3- Does Oracle, is able to handle any kind of dump et restore it in an Oracle DB or is there any constraints to respect ?

XE database has its limits - from your point of view, the most important is that it can handle up to 12GB of user data. Therefore, if the .dmp file doesn't contain more data than that, you should be able to import it.

Another constraint is the compatibility. Not all exports can be imported into all databases. There's a *matrix* which shows which versions *match*; it is available on My Oracle Support site (but you have to have access to it, which you - as you said - don't. Though, generally speaking, "close" Oracle database versions can interchange .dmp files. It would be best if these two database versions match, of course.

Comment: Thank you very much for all these explanations. It was very clear and it answers my questions perfectly.
I now have to dig a little deeper into the question of data weight and DB compatibility. Thanks a lot for your answer anyway! :)